# Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed in Session.php

Tags: module, session, php-7

Greetings StackOverflow.

Recently I have upgraded a Magento solution to PHP 7.0. I have used Inchoo PHP7 Compatibility module for core overrides that should make it "stable".

- https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Recently we have experienced an error with a checkout module, that throws the following error:

```
    2018/05/14 11:31:34 [error] 1523#0: *39856435 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed in /var/www/www.mydomain.com/webfiles/releases/389/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/www.mydomain.com/webfiles/releases/389/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php(99): session_write_close()
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session->__destruct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/www.mydomain.com/webfiles/releases/389/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 99" while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.mydomain.eu, request: "GET /svm/svmPayment/redirect/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.mydomain.eu", referrer: "https://www.mydomain.eu/streamcheckout/"`
```

The following error is from PHP and NGINX LOGS.

If I simply out-comment or remove "session_write_close();" from the __desctruct function everything works as before.

But my question is does anything else depend on the __destructfunction that would break the rest of the functionality?

Comment: Update: It seems like "sesson_write_close" does not accept arrays that have pipes in them... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i am running the exact same module (SWMPayment) and found a solution for you.

Can you please try `print_r($params)` as solution.
Should solve your problem.

**app/code/local/lemonline/swmpaymentmodule/model/swmpayment/abstract.php**
Line 410 in function getCheckoutParamaters

Comment: It seems like "sesson_write_close" does not accept arrays that have pipes in them... :)